# Rails 4 setting model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby on Rails 4 web application. I have a Booking model, like this:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :departureTranslated 
  @departureTranslated


  def as_json(options = { })
    h = super(options)
    h[:departureTranslated] = @departureTranslated   
    h
  end
end
```

I have a departureTranslated attribute that is not coming from the db, but calculated. I do something like:

```
booking.departureTranslated = somevalue
```

When I do:

```
puts "departureTranslated=" + booking.departureTranslated
puts "booking=" + booking.inspect
```

For first puts I get the assigned value correctly. However, if I puts the booking.inspect I can´t see the departureTranslated attribute.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails overrides the normal Ruby inspect method in [ActiveRecord::Core#inspect](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb).  This method displays the values that are associated with database columns.  If you need to display additional custom attributes you can override the `inspect` method.